# Ajax live search not working on touchscreen phones

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have implemented ajax live search on my website.It does work for all browsers but when it comes to touchscreen it doesn't show any results.I think the touch event is not being detected by the code but even upon my several searching on net I have no clue what to do.Here is my code and any help would be appreciated

```
        $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#search").keyup(function (e){

            var inp = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);

            if (/[a-zA-Z0-9-_ ]/.test(inp)) {

                $.ajax({

                    url: '/search.php',

                    type: 'POST',

                    data: "keyword=" + $(this).val(),

                    success: function (data) {

                        data = $.parseJSON(data);

                        if (data['response'] == true) {

                            $("#search_results").html(data['html']).show();

                        } else {

                            alert("Please try again.");

                        }

                    }

                });

            }

        });



        function hide_search_results(e) {

            var container = $("#search_results");

            if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {

                window.displayBoxIndex = -1;

                container.hide();

            }

        }



        $(document).mouseup(function (e) {

            hide_search_results(e);

        });

    });
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you also need `touchend` event to make you script supporting touch screens.

Try to use two events with `.on()` instead of `.keyup()`.

```
$('#search').on('touchend keyup', function(e) {
  ...
});
```

As an alternative you can use `input` event instead of `touchend`.

Comment: Thanks a lot it has started working  but the problem is now with this line  var inp = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode) .It is not fetching the exact input from touchscreen. Can you help me regarding this issue.

Comment: Right, there can be a problem too because `e.keyCode` is a property of `keydown / keyup` events and won't work with other events. Is it necessary to get inputted text in this way? Perhaps, `$(this).val()` might be good as well? Or there're some other needs to use `String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode)`?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time. There was no specific reason for using String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode) So I have changed it to $(this).val() now and everything is working fine.